# Oracle join tables while passing parameters from one table to function which returns table

Tags: oracle, function, join, parameters

I have function which returns a table and I want to join that returned table with second table but I have to pass parameters from second table to function first.

Second table:

Table2

```
|COLUMN1|COLUMN2|
```

Function which returns first table

```
SELECT GET_THREE_VALUES(Table2.COLUMN1) TABLE1 FROM DUAL

|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|
```

And for result I want to have joined table from function and second table like this

```
|COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|
```

Comment: Whats the connecting link( a common column) between the columns of Table2 and those returned from function? If not on what basis should the rows belong to a common row?

Comment: For this example let's say that function which returns table returns COLUMN5 which is equal to COLUMN1 from the Table2.

Comment: Show the definition of the function and some sample rows and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I understood the question; as I don't have your tables, I tried to *mimic* what you've said with Scott's tables.

First, create some types which will be used by a function.

```
SQL> create or replace type t_dep_row as object
  2    (deptno   number,
  3     dname    varchar2(30),
  4     loc      varchar2(30));
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_dep_tab is table of t_dep_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

A function itself: it accepts department number and returns additional department info. It's kind of *stupid* as in Scott's schema it returns just one dept, but never mind that.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_dep(par_deptno in number)
  2    return t_dep_tab
  3  is
  4    l_tab t_dep_tab := t_dep_tab();
  5  begin
  6    for cur_r in (select rownum rn, deptno, dname, loc
  7                  from dept
  8                  where deptno = par_deptno)
  9    loop
 10      l_tab.extend;
 11      l_tab(cur_r.rn) := t_dep_row(cur_r.deptno, cur_r.dname, cur_r.loc);
 12    end loop;
 13    return l_tab;
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.

SQL> -- Does it return anything?
SQL> select * from table(f_dep(20));

    DEPTNO DNAME           LOC
---------- --------------- ----------
        20 RESEARCH        DALLAS
```

OK, let's join EMP table with a function.

```
SQL> select e.deptno, t.dname, t.loc, e.ename, e.job
  2  from emp e join table(f_dep(e.deptno)) t on t.deptno = e.deptno
  3  where e.deptno <= 20
  4  order by e.deptno, e.job;

    DEPTNO DNAME           LOC        ENAME      JOB
---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------
        10 ACCOUNTING      NEW YORK   MILLER     CLERK
        10 ACCOUNTING      NEW YORK   CLARK      MANAGER
        10 ACCOUNTING      NEW YORK   KING       PRESIDENT
        20 RESEARCH        DALLAS     FORD       ANALYST
        20 RESEARCH        DALLAS     SMITH      CLERK
        20 RESEARCH        DALLAS     JONES      MANAGER

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

We've got something. So, that would be *how* to do it. Try to apply it to your case and see what happens. Good luck!